# Check for duplicate user from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to check for duplicates in a MySQL database when registering an user.

If the user exists display an error to that effect, else sign up.

I know there's a few questions like this but I found it hard to paste any of them into my code.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    //two passwords are the same
    if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmedpassword']) {

        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO members(username, password)"
            . "VALUES ('$username','$password')";

            //if query is successful redirect to login.php
            if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true)
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'Success';
            header("location: login.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "User couldnt be added";
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords dont match";
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue is coming? You need to execute select query first to check if user already exists or not.

Comment: I need it to check for duplicate user. It is not checking at the moment

Comment: Where you are checking for duplicate user?

Comment: I am not.  I need before posting - to check if user already exists

Comment: you can use ajax for that.

Comment: Even if you check it on the client you should check it on the server, JS is easy to override

Comment: Yes you need to use jquery/ajax if you want to check the user exists or not or you can do it with bootstrap formValidation with ajax.

Comment: **Don't go live with this code** nor with the code you've been given as answers. **You will get hacked** and nobody even whispered a word about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added some `salt` to your `md5` `password` to make it seem more secure, but actually this solution is not secure either. To encrypt passwords in `PHP` it is advisable to use the `password_hash()` function like this:

```
$pass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

> password_hash() creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm.

and later test it with `password_verify()`:

```
password_verify ( $passToTest , $knownPasswordHash );
```

more the functions here: [http://php.net/password-hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), [http://php.net/password-verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Also, since you are using `MySQLi` consider using prepared statements, or at least properly filter your input data before applying it to the database.
More on prepared statements: [http://php.net/prepared-statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

I added a `select statement` to check if the `user` already exists in the `table` prior to adding the `user` to the `database`.

When using `header()` to change page location put `exit()` or `die()` in the next line of code if you want to exit immediately and don't want other code to execute.

**Here is your code with the addition of the select statement:**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    //two passwords are the same
    if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmedpassword']) 
    {
        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

        // You might consider using salt when storing passwords like this
        $salt = 'aNiceDay';
        $password = md5(md5($_POST['password'].$salt).$salt);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

        $sql = "SELECT `username` FROM members WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            echo 'User exists.';
            // Do something.
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO members(username, password) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."')";

            if($mysqli->query($sql) === true)
            {
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'Success';
                header("location: login.php");
                // Important to put exit() after header so other code
                // doesn't get executed.
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "User couldn't be added";
                echo "User couldn't be added.";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords dont match";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I agree, I will edit to provide more insight for future readers. Though, I was having a similar conversation yesterday [https://stackoverflow.com/#comment83630798_48303013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302267/how-to-remove-text-overlapping-in-table/48303013#comment83630798_48303013) :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you can check that the user exists or not.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        //two passwords are the same
        if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmedpassword']) {

        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

        //Check user
        $CheckUserIsExist = mysqli->query("SELECT uid FROM members WHERE username='$username'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($CheckUserIsExist)==0 ){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO members(username, password)"
            . "VALUES ('$username','$password')";

            //if query is successful redirect to login.php
            if($mysqli->query($sql) === true)
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'Success';
                header("location: login.php");

    }
   } else{
      echo 'This username is already in use. Please use different username';
   }
   else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "User couldn't be added";
   }
}
else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords don't match";
}
```