# How to remove text overlapping in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

The responsive table with a border has been designed. The problem is wraptexting, even when included `th.nowrap` in css, where data is overlapping and two horizontal lines appear when I look into the mobile view.

I had declared nowrap text in css and even `td` and `th` but its not working.

How can I solve this wraptext error?

```js
<div class="row">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <!-- /.panel-heading -->
  <div class="panel-body pn">
   <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <br>
    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-bordered mbn">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <span class="panel-title">
        <span class="fa fa-table"></span>
        <font color="blue">Se</font>
       </span>
      </div>
      <thead>
      <tr>
       <th style="width:7.8%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <font color="grey">Enq</font>
       </th>
       <th style="width:7.8%;white-space:nowrap;" nowrap="nowrap">
        <font color="grey">Da</font>
       </th>
       <th style="width:9.9%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <font color="grey">Bu</font>
       </th>
       <th style="width:9.9%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <font color="grey">Prop</font>
       </th>
       <th style="width:17.9%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <font color="grey">Pr</font>
       </th>
       <th style="width:9.8%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <font color="grey">District</font>
       </th>
       <th style="width:9.9%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <font color="grey">City</font>
       </th>
       <th style="width:9.8%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <font color="grey">Bedrooms</font>
       </th>
       <th style="width:7.9%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <font color="grey">Details</font>
       </th>
       <th style="width:7.8%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <font color="grey">Update</font>
       </th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
       <td style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
       <td style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
       <td style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
       <td style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
       <td style="width:18%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
       <td style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
       <td style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
       <td style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
       <td style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;"><a>Det </a></td>
       <td style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;"><a> ed </a></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```css
table {
 width: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th {
 display: block;
}

tr:after {
 content: ' ';
 display: block;
 visibility: hidden;
 clear: both;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

thead th {
 height: 40px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 /*text-align: left;*/
}

tbody {
 height: 40px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

thead {
 /* fallback */
}

tbody td, thead th {
 width: 19.2%;
 float: left;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Try to clean up the code so that the HTML is actually valid...

Comment: style="width:7.8% doesn't it creates warpping text.?

Comment: I don't know. Use a proper code editor that highlights invalid HTML and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted. I removed all the `nowrap` code, as you didn't need it to achieve the `responsive layout`.

The key here is to give the tables `parent` element `position:relative;`, `float:left;` and a  width `width:100%;` so the table's `width:100%;` has a meaning. (100% of what?).

You also don't need to give every column a `width`. It's enough to provide widths for `one row` and the rest of the `table` will use `those rules`.

There was a `<div>` inside the table which I removed to above the table.

Here is the code: (run the snippet)

**Note:** the borders on the `th` are there just to show the `width of each`. I also changed the `width` of the `widest column` from `18%` to `14%` and gave the `4%` to the last two columns (`2% each`).

```css
.table-responsive
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

table
{
  width: 100%;
}

th
{
  color:grey;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

td
{
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
               
  <div class="panel panel-default">

  <!-- /.panel-heading -->
  <div class="panel-body pn">


    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">

      <br>
      <div class="table-responsive">
      
       <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="panel-title">
        <span class="fa fa-table"></span><font color="blue">Se</font></span>
       </div>
      
        <table class="table table-bordered mbn">
        <tr>
          <th style="width:8%;">Enq</th>
          <th style="width:8%;">Da</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Bu</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Prop</th>
          <th style="width:14%;">Pr</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">District</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">City</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Bedrooms</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Details</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Update</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Det</td>
          <td>ed</td> 
        </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Use this code

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <p>Some default panel content here.</p>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Test</td>
                <td>Test</td>
                <td>Test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to use this to adjust table head and table data. <th style="width:7.8%">. when i use this text is wrapping.

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code

```
<div class="row">

                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <!-- /.panel-heading -->

                   <div class="panel-body pn">


     <div style="overflow-x:auto;">

       <br>
     <div class="table-responsive">

     <table class="table table-bordered mbn">

    <div class="panel-heading">
    <span class="panel-title">
   <span class="fa fa-table"></span><font color="blue">Se</font></span>

        </div>
<thead>
<tr>
   <th style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;"><font color="grey">Enq</font></th>
  <th style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;" nowrap="nowrap"><font color="grey">Da</font></th>
  <th style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"><font color="grey">Bu</font></th>
  <th style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"><font color="grey">Prop</font></th>
  <th style="width:18%;white-space:nowrap;"><font color="grey">Pr</font></th>
  <th style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;""><font color="grey">District</font></th>
  <th style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"><font color="grey">City</font></th>
   <th style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"><font color="grey">Bedrooms</font></th>
  <th style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;"><font color="grey" >Details</font></th>
  <th style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;"><font color="grey">Update</font></th>

</tr>
</thead>

     <tr>           

        <td style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
        <td style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
        <td style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
        <td style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
        <td style="width:18%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
        <td style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
        <td style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
        <td style="width:10%;white-space:nowrap;"></td>
        <td style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;">Det </a></td>
        <td style="width:8%;white-space:nowrap;"> ed </a></td>  

    </tr>



 </table>

  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to what you've changed and why, why should the OP use this code, etc. That goes for both your answers :)

Comment: 7.8% is not working properly because point value not considerable...That's why I have used 8%. I think my first answer and this ans. are not same... in first answer I have used proper table coding same as bootstrap.

Comment: Don't explain to me :) I meant, edit your answer to provide more details on what you have done, (maybe why it will work), etc.

Comment: Cleared your answer? Look at my answer, it might not be what the OP wants but it at least explains what I did and why. And, you can run and test it. Try adding explanations to your answers and possibly make snippets to prove what you are saying. I'm not saying your answer is bad, I'm just suggesting how to improve them (for the benefit of the future readers also).

Comment: for the benefit of the future readers = My suggestion is don't using inline style and also point value...
if any user used bootstrap then we can used default table css it's very useful to us.

Comment: you give me no option but to `downvote` your answers.. I will come back later to see if you edited and if not I will `downvote` them. It's easy to copy and paste code from the internet, but you also need to explain it (not in the comments).